# QTooltip with absolute position that still moves relative to parent

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm building a custom combobox, from a (subclassed) QLineEdit and QListWidget for the dropdown menu

I'm setting the window flags to QTool so that its a floating window but doesnt steal focus from the lineedit (since the user needs to be able to input text to filter the list). This works fine but the list is now completely detached from the parent widget, so I can drag the top menu bar and move it away from the list which I don't want.

**Is there a way to use QTool or QTooltip but keep it parented to a widget?**

One other method would be setting the window flags to QPopup, in which case the popup closes when the top menu bar is clicked so cannot be dragged away. However with QPopup it steals focus from the line edit

Below is a simple example illustrating the issue:

````
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

import sys

class LineEditClickable(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    """Custom QLineEdit to detect clicked, focus and key events

Signals: clicked, focusOut, arrowUp, arrowDown
    """
    clicked = QtCore.Signal(QtGui.QMouseEvent)
    def __init__(self, value=''):
        super(LineEditClickable, self).__init__(value)

        # remove border on Mac
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_MacShowFocusRect, 0)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """Emit clicked signal"""
        self.clicked.emit(event)
        super(LineEditClickable, self).mousePressEvent(event)

class popup(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, widget=None):    
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.list = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        layout.addWidget(self.list)

        # adjust the margins or you will get an invisible, unintended border
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.adjustSize()

        # tag this widget as a popup
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.Tool)
        # self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)

    def update(self, widget):
        # calculate the botoom right point from the parents rectangle
        point        = widget.rect().bottomRight()

        # map that point as a global position
        global_point = widget.mapToGlobal(point)

        # by default, a widget will be placed from its top-left corner, so
        # we need to move it to the left based on the widgets width
        self.move(global_point - QtCore.QPoint(self.width(), 0))

    def show_popup(self, widget):
        self.update(widget)
        self.show()

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.le = LineEditClickable(self)
        self.le.clicked.connect(self.handleOpenDialog)

        self.le.move(250, 50)

        self.resize(600, 200)

        self.popup = popup(self, self.le)
        self.popup.list.addItems(['one','two','three'])

    def handleOpenDialog(self):
        self.popup.show_popup(self.le)
        self.popup.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````

Comment: Just to be clear, why are you using this class? Besides the matter about the focus, what is the special behavior you're looking for and that a QComboBox doesn't have?

Comment: I started customizing a QComboBox so much it because easier to do it this way. I'm building a widget that emulates this design: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples
(with the animations)

Comment: @MichaelB According to the link and what you describe you do not want a QComboBox but a QCompleter. Please use `@username`

Comment: @eyllanesc i've implemented my own logic instead of using a QCompleter and that's all working fine. My only issue is keeping my listwidget fixed to the parent widget without stealing focus from the line edit. I've described the two flags (Popup and Tool) i've tried (i've actually tried all of them) and the problems with each of them

Comment: @MichaelB besides the animations and the "top label", what is the *actual* difference you need from the default behavior of the QCompleter popup? Is it that you want to show all elements when the line edit receives focus and has no text yet?

Comment: @musicamante if the QCompleter popup can achieve the desired result surely there is a way I can replicate that? Maybe I could rebuild some things to use a QCompleter popup but i've already put in a lot of work building my own. I was hoping the answer would be something simple like setting some window flags..

Comment: @MichaelB the QCompleter popup already meets your requirements: it keeps the keyboard focus on the QLineEdit, it closes when clicking anywhere (which also happens if you try to move the window, obviously); what else do you need?

Comment: well its not the answer to my original question.. I think its still a useful thing to know - how to use QTool or QTooltip but ensure it moves with its parent widget?

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer to your question is to use the correct flags and focus options.

If you look at how QCompleter [`implements`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/util/qcompleter.cpp#L1237) `setPopup()`, you'll see the following:

```
popup->setWindowFlag(Qt::Popup);
popup->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
[...]
popup->setFocusProxy(d->widget);
```

As you've already experienced, `Tool` is not a good option: while avoids stealing focus from the line edit, it also has issues with any mouse click that happens outside the UI.

If you still want to use `Tool`, you *could* update the widget position, by installing an event filter on the top level window of the line edit and intercept its move events, but it's not guaranteed that it works and totally depends on the platform you're using it. For example, on certain Linux window managers you only receive it when the mouse is released *after* dragging the window.

```
class popup(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    _widget = None
    _window = None

    # ...

    def show_popup(self, widget):
        if self._window:
            self._window.removeEventFilter(self)
        self.update(widget)
        self.show()
        self._widget = widget
        self._window = widget.window()
        self._window.installEventFilter(self)

    def hideEvent(self, event):
        if self._window:
            self._window.removeEventFilter(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self._window:
            self._window.removeEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Move:
            self.update(self._widget)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Frankly, I'd suggest you to use what Qt already provides you without trying to reinvent the wheel. In your case, use a QCompleter and reimplement what you need for it's popup.

Note that if you want to show all items when the line edit gets focus and there's no text yet, you could change the completion mode.

```
class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # ...
       self.textChanged.connect(self.showCompleter)

    def showCompleter(self):
        completer = self.completer()
        if not completer:
            return
        if not self.text():
            completer.setCompletionMode(completer.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        else:
            completer.setCompletionMode(completer.PopupCompletion)
        completer.complete()
```

You might want to do the same also in the `keyPressEvent` override, *after* calling the base class implementation and ensuring that the popup is not yet visible.